# Microsoft.JScript Compilation Errors

Tags: c#, jscript

I am trying to use a Script to evaluate custom functions

Script.js

```
interface ICustomClass
{
   function get ConvertFloatToHex(floatValue : float) : String;
}

class CustomScriptEvaluator
{
    static var CustomClass : ICustomClass;

    function CustomScriptEvaluator(CustomClass : ICustomClass)
    {
        CustomScriptEvaluator.CustomClass = CustomClass;
    }
    static function Evaluate(expression : String) : String
    {
        return eval(expression);
    }
}
```

I use the jsc command to get the Script.dll from the Script.js file. 
Implementing the interface ICustomClass

CustomClass.cs

```
public class CustomClass : ICustomClass
{
    public string ConvertFloatToHex(float floatValue)
    {
        const string hex="0";
        return (hex + "h");
    }
}
```

ScriptEvaluator.cs

```
public ScriptEvaluator
{
    //Private Member declaration...

    public static ScriptEvaluator Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(m_instance==null)
            {
                m_instance = new ScriptEvaluator(ICustomClass customClass);
            }
            return m_instance;
        }
    }
    private ScriptEvaluator(ICustomClass customClass)
    {
        CustomClass = customClass;
        var instancing = new CustomScriptEvaluator(CustomClass);
    }
    public string Evaluate(String script)
    {
        return CustomScriptEvaluator.Evaluate(script);
    }
}
```

When I am using something like:

```
var result = ScriptEvaluator.Instance.Evaluate("CustomClass.ConvertFloatToHex(2.5,26,12)=='0h' ");
```

That sentence executes correctly, no matter that the number of parameters is **wrong**. So, I would like it to send an excepcion when this happens.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance.